# Why do I need to wrap an ImageView into a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is a simple layout:

```
      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" <!-- notice I've limited a height -->
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#20526d" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The height of an image I will set by `setImageBitmap()` is more that 40dp. 
Using this layout I have an extra space between `ImageView` and `TextView`, where did it come from? 
[image]

But after I wrap the `ImageView` with `FrameLayout` I don't have this unnecessary extra space:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_container"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#20526d" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

Can you guys explain why shall I put `ImageView` into `FrameLayout` to have things as intended? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try to use a LinearLayout instead of Relativelayout as a parent. RelativeLayout proved buggy on many occasions.

Comment: You have to assign android:layout_width="80dp or 100dp" to your ImageView.

Dont worry your image would not stretch/compress

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> The height of an image I will set by setImageBitmap() is more that 40dp. Using this layout I have an extra space between ImageView and TextView, where did it come from?

Since the `android:layout_height="40dp"` with a `android:scaleType="fitStart"`, the image is getting scaled down (and to the left/start) to fit the height, so this "extra space" is actually the original width of the image, since your `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. I recreated your layout with my own image that is larger than `40dp`. When you select the `ImageView`, you can see that its bounds stretch to the image's original width.

[image: Original Layout]

To further prove this, if I set `android:scaleType="center"`, no fit is applied and you can see the `ImageView`'s original width.

[image: Original Layout not scaled to fit]

> Can you guys explain why shall I put ImageView into FrameLayout to have things as intended?

It appears that since your `FrameLayout` uses `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, it gets the correct scaled down width from your `ImageView` after it gets scaled due to `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. It is strange that the `ImageView` itself uses `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, but shows the original image's width, and not the scaled width. My **hunch** is that the height and width of `ImageView`s get set **before** the scaling is applied, so the `ImageView` gets the original image's width, but the parent `FrameLayout` gets the scaled width of it's `ImageView` child **after** the scaling is applied. This may not be true, but it appears that way to me.

However, you can solve the unscaled width issue (without using a `FrameLayout`) by using `android:maxHeight="40dp"` on the `ImageView`. You can then set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so your images can be smaller than `40dp` if the image is smaller.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/companyIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

[image: Original Layout using maxHeight]

Answer (score 4):

This applies to almost all the view but answer is written considering specifically `ImageView`

**Guideline to set Height and Width**

Choose one of this three options only.

1. Set **both** height and width to "`WRAP_CONTENT`"
2. Set **both** height and
   width to "`FILL_PARENT`"
3. Set **both** height and width to "`FIXED SIZE`"

   ***Avoid** using mixture of them say `Width=WRAP_CONTENT and Height=FILL_PARENT`

---

**Guideline to set SCALETYPE for ImageView**

*What does ScaleType do?*

> It scale the image you set to the ImageView, It doesn't scale
>   ImageView so when you set it to fitStart it will scale your image and
>   show on the right but your imageView will remain same in terms of
>   height and width as what you have specified.

As if you are using `WRAP_CONTENT` for height and width you *don't need to specify* ScaleType cause your ImageView is automatically going to be as big as your image.

As if you are using `FILL_PARENT` for height and width you will have option to show the image in Center,Start,End or in Full view.. so *based on that you can choose* your ScaleType.

As if you are using `FIXED_SIZE` fpr height and width you *should opt* for `scaletype=FITXY`.

---

**Guideline to set Image into ImageView**

As if you are setting image **statically** in XML then you have one image on your hand so you can create image of the size you wish as per your layout design and just **move on with WRAP_CONTENT**.

As if you are setting image at **runtime** after downloading it from somewhere, that time **download the image and create bitmap of the size** you prefer and then set it to ImageView

---

**Specific to your case**

You can see that your image is quite stretched and the text is not readable that's because you have downloaded and set image as it is but in smaller height and width.. rather you should have done like,

Set ImageView height and width to `WRAP_CONTENT` in XML file

```
                    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Download image in your required size say 50X100, for example see this code

```
class LoadPics extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Bitmap> {
    String urlStr;
    ImageView iv;
    int width, height;

    public LoadPics(ImageView iv, String url, int width, int height) {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.urlStr = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                InputStream in = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
                    httpConn.connect();
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                int scale = 2;
                if (o.outHeight > width || o.outWidth > height) {
                    scale = 2 ^ (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(width
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5));
                }

                if (scale <= 1 && o.outHeight > 150) {
                    scale = 5;
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
                b1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, width, height, true);
                loader.addToCache(urlStr, b1);
                publishProgress(b1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        iv.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
    }
}
```

And call this method with your arguments,

```
new LoadPics(ivUser,imgURL,100,50).execute();
```

Comment: Nicely stated, good explanation on ImageView. Although I think the real question is: "Why is adding a FrameLayout fixing the problem?"

Comment: Yes.. Using framelayout how its working fine.. I couldn't get that.. but this is how I follow.. so I posted.. @SherifelKhatib BTW thanks for +1

Answer (score 1):

try to replace `android:scaleType="fitStart"` with this `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

---

**Edit**

in your image view you should set the width of imagView to `wrap-content` this will take the size of image. If you hard-code the `imageView's` width (as you have done it by giving the width to 40dp) then this will not look so good in other android mobile devices.

Still if you want to do so then Try to load image of lesser in resolution. if this image is `200X100` in resolution, then try to load the image of `100X50` in your `ImageView`

Comment: Proportions would not remain if I set fitXY, so it would be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `android:scaleType="FIT_END"`, without the `FrameLayout`, does that put the Subway image near the "Subway" text? I wonder, because you have `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` in there. I'm thinking that the `ImageView`'s original size before the scaling is what is throwing off the layout without a `FrameLayout`.

It probably doesn't matter too much, but it does take some processing to scale and resize the image for what you want it to do. If it is viable for what you want to do, I'd simply resize the image myself instead of relying on XML. If I wanted to cater to multiple sizes, I would have a couple of different layouts made. This of course may be overkill for your purpose, I do not know.

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` should readjust the View's bounds after scaling, though it appears it's not doing that it says it should.

Answer (score 0):

Extra space came in first image because u set match parent in image container layout. but second u used wrap content in FrameLayout which is image container.

my suggession to do these thing Create linear layout insider relative layout and apply layout_weight propert so ratio will be same in both view.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the scale type to center_inside.