# ImageView adjustViewBounds not working with Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an `ImageView` and have set its `layout_height` to "100dp" and its layout_width to "wrap_content".

The drawable used has bigger actual dimensions that are 130dp (width) X 215dp (height).

When the `ImageView` is placed inside a `LinearLayout`, if I set `adjustViewBounds` to true, it gets a width that is measured according to the drawable's aspect ratio and the layout_width.

However, when placed inside a `RelativeLayout` the `ImageView` gets the same width as the drawable (130dp), no matter the adjustViewBounds settings.

In both cases the image renders correclty without distortion, however the ImageView's bounds are different.

The RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_orange"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ImageView in Relative Layout]

The LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_orange" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: ImageView in LinearLayout]

Why does the `ImageView` measures differently in these 2 scenarios? Is there a way to make the `ImageView` behave always like being in the LinearLayout case (wrapping it with a LinearLayout works but it's not a clean solution)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="100dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

[I got it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609106/why-do-i-need-to-wrap-an-imageview-into-a-framelayout)

Comment: The image completely disappears with this.

Comment: `android:maxHeight` seems to do the trick! But why is it needed? 

Inside LinearLayout everything works as expected. Is the RelativeLayout's behaviour correct?

Comment: @Petrakeas The mystery as same as a reason to set adjustViewBounds to false by default =)

Comment: What worked for me was the `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"` along with `adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

use width and height of imageview to match_parent

```
private void addView(Drawable d) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    rl.addView(iv);
    iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```